# Is it possible to convert a member function such as bool T::operator < (const T& right) to a binary_function?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to avoid code duplication as much as possible. Suppose I have a class such as,

```
class T {
    int val;
    bool operator < (const T& right) const { return val < right.val; }
}
```

I want to be able to call std::sort() like this,

```
std::sort( SomeContainer.begin(), SomeContainer.end(), FuncAdaptedFromOp );
```

This is my very first question in StackOverflow. Please be forgiving.

**EDIT**

The problem is that the class may have multiple `bool T::Compare (const T& right)` functions. I would still like an adapter. Take this example,

```
class Edge {
    Vertex u, v;
    bool CompareSrc (const Edge& right) const { return u < right.u; }
    bool CompareDest (const Edge& right) const { return v < right.v; }
}
```

Sometimes I want to sort by source `Vertex` and sometimes by destination `Vertex`. I just want to know if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::sort(SomeContainer.begin(), SomeContainer.end()
    // or use &Edge::CompareDest if you want that instead
    , std::bind(&Edge::CompareSrc, _1, _2) );
```

`std::bind` is C++11 though, so you may want to use `boost::bind` (in which case you shouldn't use the preceding using directive) or the `bind` from TR1 if your implementation has that. Otherwise I'd advise you to handroll your own functor.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't provide a third parameter, then the < operator will be used.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

"The elements are compared using operator< for the first version, and comp for the second."

Answer (score 1):

You just duplicate STL functor `std::less` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/less/

```
template <class T> struct less : binary_function <T,T,bool> {
  bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const
    {return x<y;}
};
```

Example with less:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

struct my_struct {
   int a;
   bool operator< (const my_struct &s) const {
      return a < s.a;
   }
};

int main() {
   my_struct array[10];

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      array[i].a = 10 - i;

   std::sort(array, array + 10, std::less<my_struct>());

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      std::cout << array[i].a << ", ";
}
```

You don't need to write it.
Algorithm `std::sort` has two versions:

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
  void sort ( RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last );

template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
  void sort ( RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp );
```

First version may be used when your class provides `operator <` (is comparable). Second version is used if you don't want use `operator <` or it doesn't exist.

Example without less:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

struct my_struct {
   int a;
   bool operator< (const my_struct &s) const {
      return a < s.a;
   }
};

int main() {
   my_struct array[10];

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      array[i].a = 10 - i;

   std::sort(array, array + 10);

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      std::cout << array[i].a << ", ";
}
```

The examples have the same result.

Also you can use others functors to change behavior of sort algorithms such as `std::greater`.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted. I am sorry my question was not clear enough earlier.